# Uncaught ReferenceError: make_basic_auth is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, authentication, xmlhttprequest

Like the title says: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: make_basic_auth is not defined"*

I have a sensor that is connected to the app via bluethooth. The app sends the data to the cloud service. I got a link from the cloud service that contains the data in a json format and I have to GET the data from it.

**make_basic_auth** is a function to authentificate my GET request.

Im new and I dont have a clue what I did wrong.

```html
<html>

 <head>

  <title>Test</title>

  <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Base64Toolkit.js"></script>

 </head>

  <body>
  <button onclick="myFunctionPost()">Post</button>
  <div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
  <script>

   function make_base_auth(user, password) {
     var tok = user + ':' + pass;
     var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
     return "Basic " + hash;
   }

   var auth = make_basic_auth('myUSERNAME','myPASSWORD');
   var url = 'myURL';

   // RAW
   xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xml.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
   xml.open('GET',url)

   // ExtJS
   Ext.Ajax.request({
       url : url,
       method : 'GET',
       headers : { Authorization : auth }
   });

   // jQuery
   $.ajax({
       url : url,
       method : 'GET',
       beforeSend : function(req) {
           req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
       }
   });

   function myFunctionPost() {
    var getJSON = function(url) {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('get', url, true);
      xhr.responseType = 'json';
      xhr.onload = function() {
       var status = xhr.status;
       if (status == 200) {
        resolve(xhr.response);
       } else {
        reject(status);
       }
      };
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
      xhr.send();
     });
    };

    getJSON('myURL').then(function(data) {
    alert('Your Json result is:  ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug

    result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
    }, function(status) { //error detection....
    alert('Something went wrong.');
    });
   }

  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

- `make_base_auth` <- defined
- `make_basic_auth` <- used